# How do I block specific key presses using Python e.g. Alt + F4, Alt + Tab?

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard

I'm trying to develop an application for Windows which requires me to block certain key combinations from working such as Alt + F4 and Alt + Tab.

I have tried using the keyboard module to achieve this but it still will not work. Is there something I am missing or is there another way to block keys.

I am using Tkinter as the GUI for the application so this must work while I am using Tkinter and not just the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want or am I missing something?

```
keyboard.add_hotkey("alt + f4", lambda: None, suppress =True)
keyboard.add_hotkey("alt + tab", lambda: None, suppress =True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give another function? I haven't tried

```
root.bind(<"alt + f4">, somefunction)
```